# Rails 5 Caching, where is it stored and how to clean it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm breaking my head over this. I can't a find a way to clear the production cache of a ROR5 app, other then restart `nginx`. If i change something (for example) in **app/views/layouts/application.html** then the changes are not reflected until i reload/restart the server.

I edited **config/environments/production.rb** and changed:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

also tried to set

```
config.cache_store = false
```

I guess, there are so many caching elements in  ROR i lost my way.

I would like to know the following:

1. How (where) to disable cache in **production** mode?
2. Which part is responsible for **view** caching?
3. Where is the cache stored (cache_store? tmp/*)?
4. Is there anyway to **force** ROR to refresh its cache (while running)?

*On a site-note: I'm running the app on a Raspberry Pi, I need to fix a few things, and I push my changes direct via ftp to the box. I know this is not the best way to fix it, but restarting nginx takes some time. I know i could swap the box into development mode, but i don't want to do that right now.*

Thanks!

Comment: you can write a rake task and perform it in background. there are a rake command for clear cash, also you can make a new rake task and perform several task of cleaning inside of your that task.

Answer (score 7):

There are actually several rake tasks that need to be run on each deployment to ensure a clean slate:

```
rails tmp:clear # clears all cache and sockets files.
rails db:schema:cache:clear # Clears a db/schema_cache.dump
rails assets:precompile # Compile all the assets
rails db:migrate 
# ... + a few things I already forgot.
rails restart
```

Doing this manually is going to be a PITA. Instead use [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/rails) and setup an automated deployment process. With `Capistrano::Rails` it should be pretty much plug and play.

Comment: The complicated answer is that the cache is stored in several different places. See the rails guide for a full rundown http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: Also since the Pi is pretty light on resources you might want to compile the assets locally and just upload the assets instead of trying to compile on the Pi. But I would choose a free tier Heroku app instead of a Pi unless you need to run it on a closed network.

Comment: thanks, i'm aware of that (and the tasks). But this is about trying some fixes that won't show unless i restart the server (which is cumbersome). Basically i want prod. mode, without cache. I read the manual, but its not clear where the views are cached (i don't use any cache commands). So Rails is doing a few things on its own (fragments?). Not a clue :-/